# Как проверить наличие опциональных типов?

Tags: c++, типы, проверка

Есть опциональные типы. Например, `int32_t`. Можно ли как-то из кода проверить их наличие? Типа макроса `INT32T_DEFINED`.

Comment: Наверное `INT16_MIN` можно проверить, но это не особо практично

Comment: @user7860670 этот макрос тоже опциональный

Comment: @Queen ну и правильно, если макрос не объявлен, то и типа нет.

Comment: @gbg а, ну логично, согласен. Хотя не уверен, что не может быть ситуации, когда типа нет, а этот макрос объявлен

Comment: Вам нужна проверка только на целочисленные типы вида `(u)intN_t`, `N = 8, 16, 32, 64` или на произвольные типы?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл вообще, только на целочисленные, но решение для произвольного тоже подойдёт :)

Comment: Почти уверен, вам не надо ничего проверять. Вы видели хоть одну платформу, где этого типа бы не было?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat лично не видел, но это же не значит, что такой нет

Comment: А что вы будете делать, если такого типа нет? Наверное определите через typedef свой. Таким образом, у вас должен быть написан .h файл с этими определениями. Сделайте их под ifdef-ами, а соответствующий им файл configure.h сгенерите, просто проверяя, компилируется ли файл с объявлением этого типа (т.е. внесите в свой Makefile шаг configure) / Для практического же применения (imho, конечно) все это пустая трата времени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте наличие макросов типа `INT32_MAX`. [Гарантируется](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), что они есть только тогда, когда есть соответствующие типы:

> Each of the macros listed in below is defined if and only if the implementation defines the corresponding typedef name.

---

Только непонятно, какой в этом смысл. Если программа должна работать на платформе, где этих типов нет, то просто не используйте их. А если не должна, то и проверять незачем.

Comment: 1) Разве не может быть такое, что макрос `INT32_MAX` определён, а тип `int32_t` -- нет? 2) *Если программа должна работать на платформе, где этих типов нет, то просто не используйте их* -- но эти типы заметно упрощают работу в моей программе; если известен точный размер типа, то программа работает быстрее за счёт отсутствия проверок на количество байтов в типе

Comment: @Queen *"Разве не может быть такое"* Не может, почитайте [это](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). *"заметно упрощают работу в моей программе"* Есть `int_least32_t`.

Comment: Нашёл фразу *Each of the macros listed in below is defined if and only if the implementation defines the corresponding typedef name.*, ок, спасибо. Упрощают=ускоряют, логика кода действительно усложняется из-за дополнительной ветки `ifdef`

Comment: @Queen На каких платформах должен работать ваш код? Платформы без этих типов - большая экзотика, может вы их вообще никогда не увидите.

Comment: Желательно, чтобы на всех платформах. Может и не увижу, а может и увижу

Comment: @Queen, "если известен точный размер типа, то программа работает быстрее за счёт отсутствия проверок на количество байтов в типе" вы же в курсе, что стандарт допускает разное количество битов в байте? Ваш код учитывает, 9-битные байты или 1-байтный `int32_t`? :D

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл если делать такие проверки, то они будут в обоих вариантах: и для точных и для неточных типов, т.е. учёт/неучёт не влияет на *если известен точный размер типа, то программа работает быстрее за счёт отсутствия проверок на количество байтов в типе*

Comment: @Queen, не понял вас. Вы же сами написали, вам  нужен точный тип, чтобы исключить проверки. А теперь пишите, что для точных тоже нужны проверки. Приведите конкретный пример, где использование `int32_t` вместо `int_least32_t` ускорит вашу программу.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл новые проверки на количество битов в байте, которые вы предложили, будут и для точных и для неточных. Старые проверки на количество байт в типе нужны только для неточных. Отсюда ускорение и смысл проверки наличия точного типа. Пример: есть `int32_t` -- читаем по 4 байта в него напрямую; теперь есть только `int_least32_t` -- если он 8байт, то напрямую 4байтники уже не прочитаешь

Comment: @Queen, а почему не нужны проверки на кол-во байт для `int32_t` Он ведь может быть как 4-байтным, так и 2-байтным, так и 1-байтным. Как вы прочитаете четыре байта напрямую в `int32_t` если он будет однобайтным? И что значит напрямую? Через `memcpy`? Про порядок байтов не забыли?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл в таком случае и системный байт, который мы читаем, будет таким же. Т.е. надо будет читать не 4*8=32бита, а 1*32=32бита, и всё напрямую. Меньше байта всё равно не прочитать. Напрямую -- да, через `reinterpret_cast` или `memcpy` и т.п.. Порядок байтов влияет, но одинаково влияет на точные/неточные типы, как и проверки на биты в байте

Comment: @Queen Последний раз попытаюсь убедить. :) Советую погуглить, на каких платформах нет `int32_t`, и осознанно решить, нужно вам это проверять или нет (у меня не получается найти ни одной). Зачем писать лишний код, который никогда не пригодится?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня уже написана версия для неточных типов, а для точных должно быть проще (кстати, мой другой вопрос про это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1218099/420898). Не пригодится -- уберём в будущем, когда будут точно известны все целевые платформы. Всё равно оверхеда от ветки времени компиляции нет

Comment: @Queen Никакой потери времени в рантайме, нет, угу. Зато есть потеря времени программиста.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat потеря времени для бизнеса, для программиста -- прокачка скилов :)