# Вектор байтов в вектор интов inplace

Tags: c++, вектор, байты

Есть вектор байтов `std::vector<std::byte>`. Можно ли **на его место** записать вектор интов `std::vector<int>`?

Можно завести новый вектор и скомпоновать в него значения, вопрос же в том, как это сделать без дополнительной памяти, т.е. прямо на месте вектора байт.

Полагаем int = 4 байта, little-endian, размер исходного вектора кратен 4.

Comment: memcpy подойдет?

Comment: @Croessmah может быть, но разве при пересечении входной и выходной последовательностей там не UB?

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: у Вас есть вектор байт и вы хотите записать в него данные из другого вектора? Возможно, я не правильно понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Croessmah нет, у меня есть вектор байт. Я хочу каждые 4 байта этого вектора преобразовать в int и записать этот int не в другой вектор, а в буфер этого же вектора, чтобы в итоге исходный вектор байт воспринимался как вектор интов

Comment: если вы хотите поменять тип элементов в векторе, то сделать этого не получится. Однако, никто не запрещает Вам интерпретировать эти байты как Вы хотите, при условии, что понимаете что делаете. Можно даже написать небольшую оберточку для этого.

Comment: @Croessmah обёртка будет принимать `std::vector<std::byte>` и возвращать `std::vector<int>`? Если да, то хотелось бы увидеть пример кода

Comment: Если только вектор переписать и сделать доступ к полю, которое указывает на память...

Comment: @avp с помощью `data()` можно получить указатель на внутренний массив, если вы об этом

Comment: @Queen, нет, я имел в виду изменение этого указателя. Впрочем,  можно попробовать сделать это через аллокатор vector<int>, но вряд ли оба оъекта после этого смогут согласованно функционировать при изменении размера.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите чтобы vectorByte[0-3] воспринимались как vectorInt[0]?

Comment: Если я понял правильно Вас, то примерно вот [такой](https://pastebin.com/T7CJMiF5) код это реализует в грубом виде, дальше уже можно написать обертку

Answer (score 0):

Нет способа сделать вектор из другого вектора с отличающимся типом inplace, т.е. без копирования и приведения типов.

Все решения, которые вы найдёте, будут зависимы от платформы и скорее всего UB. Чего делать, думаю, не стоит.